# Why cant I turn on high performance ubuntu 22.04 stock setting

Tags: system-settings, 22.04, preferences

I used to use a third-party CPU controller when I was using Ubuntu 20.04, and it was a terrible experience, but now the performance settings have been introduced to 22.04, and I can't even turn it on?

[image: picture]

Comment: "Balanced" should be enough. You need to do something I don't quite remember with the CPU governor to enable performance mode but, again, balanced is fine for 99.9% of the cases.

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same problem and managed to set "performance" mode using the command line:

```
   $ powerprofilesctl set performance
```

[picture: performance-enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gZMA.png)

However, when enabling it, the gnome-control-center might fail to open.